# Solve the vector multiplication ${z\bf r}\times {\bf b} \times y|{\bf d}|r cos(\theta)$

Tags: vectors

I have vector multplication that i am attempting to do: $${\bf a} \times {\bf b}$$

Where;

- ${\bf a}={z\bf r}\times {\bf b}$ and ${\bf b}=\frac{1}{c} {\bf d}\times{\bf r}= y|{\bf d}|r cos(\theta)$
- $z$ and $y$ and $c$ are constants

How does one solve this equation?

My attempt:

Using the formula : $(\bf{a}\times\bf{b})\times\bf{c}=-(\bf{c}\bullet\bf{b})\bf{a}+(\bf{c}\bullet\bf{a})\bf{b}$

Comment: Is $\mathbf b$ vector? Really?

Comment: You said "my attempt", wrote down a formula, and then there was no attempt.